# How to use Kothari formula to find the size of a population

Tags: statistics

I am preparing for my end of semester examinations and I am trying to figure out how to use the formula proposed by Kothari in 2004 to determine the size of a population sample between 730000 and 230000. I have tried googling the formula but search results pull up pdfs and I have no time to scan them for the formula, What is the formula and how do I use it to estimate the size of a sample estimate between 230000 and 730000?

Comment: Can you provide more context, in particular the formula proposed? It's not clear from the context.

Comment: It is also called Kothari size technique

Comment: Can you check article 3.4.1 of this https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340022840_CHAPTER_THREE_RESEARCH_METHODOLOGY_30_Introduction? I don’t know the formula or its background, so idk

Comment: @insipidintegrator, Thanks for the link checking it out

Comment: Where do the numbers you're quoting come from? As far as I can tell Kothari just lays out some standard formulas for calculating sample size under some basic sampling designs and assumptions about the population, for example from [page 175 onwards](https://www.academia.edu/31050950/_C_R_Kothari_Research_Methodology_Methods_and_T_bookos_z1_org_).